# is .eth a true TLD and belongs to DNS (Domain Name System)?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am reading blog posts about auctions of Etereum domian names under .eth suffix (going sky high in bidding), and I wonder, is .eth a really supported TLD ?

Because nslookup fails to resolve an ".eth" TLD:

```
[niko@localhost ~]$ nslookup -q=NS com
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
com nameserver = d.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = k.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = c.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = l.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = g.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = f.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = j.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = a.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = m.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = b.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = e.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = h.gtld-servers.net.
com nameserver = i.gtld-servers.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:

[niko@localhost ~]$ nslookup -q=NS eth
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find eth: NXDOMAIN

[niko@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an official TLD.

The ICANN [list](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) of Top Level Domains is available from [here](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en).  As you will see, .eth is not on it.

There are a number of unofficial TLDs that are set up by individual companies, and made available for money.

After all, StackOverflow itself can tell you how to do it...
[What stops anyone from making their own top-level domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16483920/2870922)

The .eth TLD is one of these.  Set up by [ENS](https://ens.domains/).  It is quite possible that .eth will become an official TLD in time, this has happened with similar unofficial TLDs in the past, e.g. .church.

Comment: I kind of suspected that it has no validity in the real world, but just wanted a clarification.

Comment: `.domains` is a valid TLD , they just registered a new domain name called `ens`, with resulting fqdn `ens.domains`